# Load content via Ajax WITHOUT a Hash

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

What I am trying to do is load content via Ajax on a site. So suppose we have this as the main page `example.com/blankpage` (I have used htaccess to get rid of the .html part). Currently I have this working, I click a link on the page that directs to `mysite.com/blankpage#PAGE1` and the Ajax script will load all the text from `PAGE1.html` and place it into a div on `blankpage`.

Now here is what I am actually trying to do. Pretend I have another link on the page as such: `mysite.com/blankpage?action=PAGE2`. Clicking on the button works and it actually does load the contents of the file, however it only does so after loading a new page. It doesn't actually load PAGE2, it loads the `blankpage` and then replaces the contents of the div with the contents of `PAGE2`, which is what I want, but without a page load/refresh.

For the past hour I have been trying to find an error in my Ajax loading script but then it occurred to me that it might be the hash tag. Do Ajax page loads NEED `#` or am I actually making a mistake somewhere.

I can post the code if need be.

Comment: Do you own the server?

Comment: Yes, it is on my local network using XAMPP. I am on my laptop but the server is on my desktop. Accessing it through the IP and not a shared path.

@sagar-naliyapara, the title may be similar but we are having very different issues. I have no problem loading pages directly.

Answer (score 2):

you can try jquery `load()` function.
I think it's useful for your requirement.

like div has is "blankPage".
so you can do like this

```
$('#blankPage').load(your url);
```

in this load  function you can return your view and put this blankPage div.